# Query optimization, get rid of subqueries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3, but its SQL support is rather standard, so as long as the SQL doesn't contain any proprietary extensions all should be good. My schema is the following:

```
create table test (
    _id integer primary key,
    name text, 
    enabled integer not null default 1
);
create table task (
    _id integer primary key, 
    _test_id integer not null references test on delete cascade, 
    favorite integer not null default 0,
    comment text
);
```

In short: there are tests which may be enabled or not; tests have multiple tasks, which can be favorite and may have a comment.

The two most complex queries I need to write are the following:

- A select which retrieves information whether the database contains at least 1 favorite and at least 1 commented task for any enabled test (i.e. don't group by test). I came up with the following monstrosity:

  ```
  select
    exists(select task._id from task as task inner join test as test on task._test_id=test._id where task.favorite=1 and test.enabled=1 limit 1) as has_favorite,
    exists(select task._id from task as task inner join test as test on task._test_id=test._id where task.comment is not null and test.enabled=1 limit 1) as has_commented;
  ```
- A select which retrieves test core data (id, name etc.) along with information about its task count, whether the test contains at least 1 favorite and at least 1 commented task. I came up with this:

  ```
  select
      test.*,
      (select count(*) from task where _test_id=test._id) as task_count,
      exists(select _id from task where favorite=1 and _test_id=test._id limit 1) as has_favorite,
      exists(select _id from task where comment is not null and _test_id=test._id limit 1) as has_commented
  from test as test where test.enabled=1 order by test._id asc
  ```

Actually, the 'has_favorite' and 'has_commented' info are not the only ones, but they depict my doubts - these queries are pretty big, contain a fair amount of subqueries (and I read subselects are bad for performance) and duplication.

The question: would it be possible to write the queries more easily? Make them better, more concise? Not duplicate so much? For example, I'm thinking maybe there is a way to perform only one join between the task and test tables and somehow derive the data from there.

**Edit:** so it appears I can write this for the first one:

```
    select
        count(*) as task_count,
        max(task.favorite) as has_favorite,
        count(task.comment) as has_commented
    from task as task inner join test as test on task._test_id=test._id where test.enabled=1;
```

and this for the second one:

```
select
    test.*,
    count(*) as task_count,
    max(task.favorite) as has_favorite,
    count(task.comment) as has_commented
from task as task inner join test as test on task._test_id=test._id where test.enabled=1 group by test._id;
```

If max(task.favorite) is anything > 0 it means at least 1 task is favorite. I could replace it with 'sum(task.favorite)' and if the sum > 0, there is a favorite.

Is this any better than the original proposals (with exists(subselect))? It seems way easier.

Comment: Do yo have version 3.8.3 or later (which has common table expressions)?

Comment: I should be running on 3.8.4.3 (Android Lollipop, 5.0), but I might have to be compatible as far back as 3.7.4 (Android 4.0). I would be curious, however, what your take would be.

Comment: [WITH clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html). You could just create a view instead.

Comment: I read about the 'with' clause and basically it just creates a temporary view, if I understand it correctly. Could you show an example how I could use it, and maybe tell how it makes the query better/faster? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually went with joins similar to the ones in my edits as they worked quite nicely and also allowed be to gather other information as well in one go.